# Solving nonlinear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, finite-element-method

I want to solve a coupled system of nonlinear second order pde in 2D. There is no time derivative in equations.
How I can discrete the equations and solve them using Finite Element Method?

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like you usually do, derive a weak formulation and approximate your test functions and solution variables using Galerkin's approximation. After this, you will end up with a system of nonlinear equations, which you then can solve by using e.g. Newton's method.